# Sprockets max-age header on heroku

Tags: heroku, sprockets, s-maxage

My application.js file name looks like `application-b600352536291bc180983d43e6a2407f.js`. So it has the md5 cache buster in its name. I have set the max-age option for static assets to 1 hour `config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"`. But i am observing that the browser is not respecting the `max-age` header and always revalidates from the server and does a round trip for a `304 Not Modified`. How can i save the round trip?

**Request Headers**

```
Request URL:https://blah.com/assets/application-b600352536291bc180983d43e6a2407f.js  
Request Method:GET  
Status Code:304 Not Modified  
Request Headersview source  
Accept:*/*  
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3  
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch  
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8  
Cache-Control:max-age=0  
Connection:keep-alive  
If-Modified-Since:Sun, 12 Feb 2012 07:36:16 GMT
```

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Sun, 12 Feb 2012 18:27:48 GMT
Last-Modified:Sun, 12 Feb 2012 07:36:16 GMT
Server:nginx
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Via:1.1 varnish
X-Varnish:499878183
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I've had similar experiences with Chrome where it's always sending 'Cache-Control:max-age=0'

Answer (score 0):

Are you pressing `Command + R` or `Ctrl + R`? The browser refresh button intentionally re-checks the freshness of its assets. It assumes you're hitting refresh because something didn't function properly on the page.

If you want to test the headers, visit the page once and then focus the location bar and press `Enter` to visit it a second time. The assets should come from the cache.